# Speeding up this matlab script

Tags: performance, matlab

I have a Matlab script that is a filter for an IR camera. It finds the window average of 5x5 and applies it to the entire image window. It takes a long time to run each iteration for each image (~.5s) compared to the native window average filter in the software. I was wondering if there was a way to speed it up.

Please find the script below:

```
h = size(rir_filter_input, 1);
w = size(rir_filter_input, 2);

if rir_filter_reset
    rir_filter_output = zeros(h, w, class(rir_filter_input));
end

%Window averaging the filter with a kernal size of 5

sz = 5;
pad = sz-1;
inimg = zeros(h+pad,w+pad); % padded image
inimg(pad/2+1:h+pad/2, pad/2+1:w+pad/2) = rir_filter_input;

for y = pad/2+1 : pad : h+pad/2
    for x = pad/2+1 : pad : w+pad/2
        win = inimg(y-pad/2:y+pad/2, x-pad/2:x+pad/2);  % get window
        rir_filter_output(y-pad/2:y+pad/2,x-pad/2:x+pad/2) = mean(win(:));      % find mean and apply to window   
    end
end
```

The script seems pretty minimal; I'm not sure how I can speed it up.

Comment: If I understand your code, what you want is a 2D convolution against a 5x5 kernel filled with 0.04, right?  You should be able to do this with a single call to `conv2`.  Alternatively do it with `ones(5,5)` and divide by 25.

Comment: You do your loops make steps of `pad‘ instead of `sz`?

Comment: Did you put this code inside a function, or are you running it as a code snippet on its own? Inside a function it will be lots faster because it will be compiled before execution.

Comment: You should also try to simplify the indexing. You do `for y = pad/2+1:…` and then use `y-pad/2:y+pad/2`. Why not loop `for y = 1:…` and then use `y:y+pad`. Simpler code usually runs faster.

Comment: Oh, a big one: swap the two loops, the y loop should be the inner one. That way you visit the image data in memory order, which is a lot faster because you’ll be using the cache better.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for the comments. I will switch the y and x for the loops. And yes, I realized a bit later it should be sz instead of pad. I will have to see if the IR camera will run the code as a function instead of a straight up snippet.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for your suggestion; I'm not sure if this is what I want. Basically I would like to take a 5x5 pixel window of let's say a 720x1080 pixel image, and compute the average in the 5x5, replacing all of the pixels in same window of the original image by the average, then striding by 5 to perform the same calculation on the next window, until the end of the image.

Comment: What is class of the image?

Comment: @JamesTursa It's a single precision array.